# jQuery disappearing div

Tags: jquery

This is probably really straightforward but I can't see the answer for the life of me.

I want the search form to toggle into view and away when I click on the word "Search".

HTML:

```
<div id="mainsearchlink">
    <a id="mainsearchlinka" href="#">Search</a>
    <div id="mainsearch">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="">
             <div>
                 <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                 <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#mainsearchlink').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('div#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

CSS:

```
#mainsearch {
    display: none;
}
```

However, the fading in and out works okay, but when I put the cursor in the input box, it fades away.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is due to event bubbling. You have the event bound to the outer `div` `mainsearchlink`. Any element you click inside that container will trigger that click event causing the `fadeToggle()` to execute, hence it toggles out when you click the search input control. As other's said you need to be more specific in what element you want to use to trigger the fade and ensure you only bind to that or use `event.target` to set which element should trigger the toggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#mainsearchlink')
```

Should be

```
$('#mainsearchlinka')
```

The reason why you need to make this change is because of event bubbling. When you click in the textbox, the click event bubbles up to your div.

But, with that change, you'll need to change your selector. So:

```
$('#mainsearchlinka').click(function (event) {
    $('#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wPQDM/1

**Edited**: to incorporate FrançoisWahl's comment.

Comment: He'll prob need to change `$(this).find('div#mainsearch')` to just `$('#mainsearch')` as well

Comment: @aquinas someone probably downvoted before you corrected the fadeToggle part, since it would've been broken.

Comment: +1. Though just using `$('#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);` is also enough, after all all identifiers should be unique in the DOM. Alternatively `$(this).next('#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);` also works and saves yourself the trip back up the DOM tree and back into the Tree `closest/find` is doing.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl that's what I said, just without the useful explanation!

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Sorry, never realized :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, Good point! I kept his find without even checking to see if it was class based. I assumed it was. Oops. Will change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mainsearchlink').click(function (event) {
    $(this).find('div#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);
});

$('#s').on('click', function (event) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: or `$('#mainsearchlink').click(function (event) { if(event.target !== this){ return }; $(this).find('div#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);
});` very handy if you would have to otherwise add `return false` to all other elements. Also allow you to still use the click events of other elements inside it.

Comment: hmm yes, I use just the quick solution :), thanks for advice.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#mainsearchlink').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('div#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

in the above script 
change `#mainsearchlink`  to `#mainsearchlinka`

Comment: -1. Even though you are correct with the selector change, the `$(this).find('div#mainsearch').fadeToggle(400);` is incorrect now. `this` is no longer a parent of `#mainsearch` when changing the selector to `#mainsearchlinka`.